# Pandas: How to count all occurrences of id before date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with unique transactionid, userid and date and I'd like to sum, all occurrences of id before the current date. Something like df bellow. I tried to do it with for loop but it's pretty slow. Can someone help me, please do it more effectively. Thanks :)

[image: df]

Comment: Yep, don't do it with a loop. What did you apply from introductory courses into pandas? What went wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['datetime] > 'your value'].count()
```

Below is the sample

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
#print(df)
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  bar    two  5  10
# 6  foo    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14

newdf = df[df['C'] > 4]
print(newdf['A'].count())

# 3
```